# How can I scrape hrefs into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, urllib, python-re

I want to distinguish between two leagues with the same name, both 'Primera Division', I wish to take the country name from the leagues' urls and append that on to the competition, creating 'Primera Division Peru' or 'Primera Division Uruguay'.

Here is a code snippet:

```
class ls:
  url = "https://www.livesoccertv.com/channels/goltv-play"
  page = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
  data = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()

df = pd.read_html(ls.data, index_col=False)[0]

df.columns = ["live", "date", "time", "hometeam", "comp"]

df.drop(columns='live', inplace=True)
df.hometeam.str.split(expand=True)
df[['hometeam', 'awayteam']] = df.hometeam.str.split(" vs ", expand=True)

df.to_csv('livesoccer.csv', index=False)
```

The result I'm getting looks like this ...

| date | time | hometeam | comp | awayteam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 Aug | 21:15 | Cerrito | Primera Division | Deportivo Maldonado |
| 17 Aug | 17:00 | Cusco | Primera Division | Carlos Manucci |

But I'd like to take the url of the comp and extract the country name from it to distinguish the two leagues from one another in the CSV file, resulting in something which would look like this ...

| date | time | hometeam | comp | awayteam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 Aug | 21:15 | Cerrito | Primera Division Uruguay | Deportivo Maldonado |
| 17 Aug | 17:00 | Cusco | Primera Division Peru | Carlos Manucci |

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: good evening, I was intending to see if I could help. I inputted your code into a notebook however I am getting the following error NameError: name 'channel' is not defined. What should be assigned to channel?

Comment: Ah, I added the channel to the url for clarity but forgot to remove the `+channel` from the code. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't even look like you need to scrape. Looks like their website relies on an API that uses this base URL https://proxy.livesoccertv.com/rss/livescores.json were .json can either be .XML or .json depending on what you want. Then add a query ?t=1629148365 (current unix time). So basically it should look like this: https://proxy.livesoccertv.com/rss/livescores.json?t=1629148365

Comment: Very interesting, there's nothing on the main site about an API that I could see. Thank you for bringing that to my attention, might just solve all my problems right there. **edit** upon further inspection that isn't quite what I was after, I'm looking for TV channel information rather than anything to do with the individual matches themselves, and need the country name to better identify which country a match is from.

Comment: @SpingoTakagi The page you're scraping seems to have some javascript that polls the URL  https://proxy.livesoccertv.com/rss/livescores.xml to update the tab you're trying to scrape so I just changed it to JSON and it worked. That's how I found the API. You could also scrape the XML, but the JSON is definitely easier.

Comment: just edited my last post, but its still very useful information to have, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using the following regex...

```
class ls:
  url = "https://www.livesoccertv.com/channels/goltv-play"
  page = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
  data = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
  html = data.decode('utf-8')
  links = re.findall(r'<td class="compcell_right" valign="[^"]*"><a href="[^"]*" class="[^"]*" title="[^"]*">[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+</a> </td>', html)
```